# Filling a XYchart excel chart programmatically?

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I'm trying to add data points to an excel chart so I basically wrote:

```
'Assume that ChartXY is a XYchart object created in an Excel sheet
Dim i as interger
Dim chartXY as Object

set chartXY = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1) 'There's one chart.

Dim PointsX(0 To 3, 0 To 0) As Double
Dim PointsY(0 To 3, 0 To 0) As Double

For i = 0 to 3
    PointsX (i,0)= i 
    PointsY (i,0)= i
Next 

With ChartXY.SeriesCollection
    If .Count = 0 then .NewSeries
        Item(1).Xvalues = PointsX
        Item(1).Yvalues = PointsY
    End If
With End
```

It doesn't seem to be working? Any ideas!

Comment: Missing a period before `Item`

Comment: @amejel Since you have solved your own question, post the details as an _answer_ rather that an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer to my question:

```
Assume that ChartXY is a XYchart object created in an Excel sheet
Dim i as interger
Dim chartXY as Object

set chartXY = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1) 'There's one chart.

Dim PointsX(0 To 3, 0 To 0) As Double
Dim PointsY(0 To 3, 0 To 0) As Double

For i = 0 to 3
    PointsX (i,0)= i 
    PointsY (i,0)= i
Next 

With ChartXY.SeriesCollection
    If .Count = 0 then .NewSeries
        Item(1).values = PointsX
        Item(1).Xvalues = PointsY
    End If
With End
```

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on Tim's comment: your two references to Item(1) need to be preceded with a dot.

```
With ChartXY.Chart.SeriesCollection
    If .Count = 0 then .NewSeries
        .Item(1).Xvalues = PointsX
        .Item(1).values = PointsY
    End If
End With
```